# JavaFX UI issue(css and colors are not appearing) in windows 10 virtual box

Tags: css, javafx, virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-10

Can any one help me on the below issue..

I am working on JavaFX and i have developed an standalone application using javafx. when i run the application in windows 10 it is working and the same is not working on windows 10 virtual box.

i have developed this application using JDK8u60 and created an executable jar file.when i run the jar file i am getting below issue.

Issue : colors of javafx ui is not appearing properly/UI shaded on virtual box. i have commented css and checked but still facing the same issue.

can any one please let me know a proper solution or root cause for this issue and let me know if any input required.

```
public class My_UI extends Application {
    public static My_Controller controller;
    private Stage stage;
    private BorderPane root;
    @Override 
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(My_UI.class.getResource("My_GUI.fxml"));
        root = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        controller = (My_Controller)loader.getController();
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false); 
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
        stage.show();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post code. Comments can't be formatted

Comment: @msparer please suggest your answers..